# How to create Startup window for my app in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create startup window for my app in WPF like the startup windows of the famous application software , the photo below show example of startup window which i need to make one likes it when my program start
[image: startup window]

Comment: Nice picture. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: There's nothing special about a startup window, just add a basic window that launches in your app before you do all your expensive loading operations.

Comment: Do you want to know how to draw that image, or how to make *an* image appear as your application starts up, or do you want an actual animated start-up window for your application?

Comment: @HighCore: Personally I'm surprised he called Microsoft Expression "famous". I barely even remember it.

Comment: you know when you open program such as Visual Studio or office , there is an startup window tell you the name of program and version without close and minimize..... etc  buttons , i want to make one like it

Comment: @MohamedSafwat change the WindowStyle property to None